# Should Puzzling SE help set Play SE in motion?

Tags: discussion

I have a concept for a Stack Exchange similar to Puzzling, but much more casual, and it doesn't really have a home. I am wondering if Puzzling SE would be a good community to get it off the ground with. If not, just leave a couple of down-votes and I'll get the idea.

The Play Stack Exchange would be primarily challenge-oriented like Puzzling SE. We would host casual challenges such as the following game-themed ideas (but it wouldn't be limited to games):

- Where am I: The asker posts a non-UI, first person screenshot of some
  unnamed game, with enough information in the picture for answerers to
  work out which game it is and where in the game they are
- Treasure Hunt: The asker details a particular section of a game and
  requires some particular information that answerers can only find by
  going to that section of the game and looking for it
- Spot the Fake: The asker shows a few pictures, most of which are from
  a particular game but one of which has been digitally altered in a
  way that reveals it isn't from the game. The answerer has to explain
  which picture is fake and how they know.

I believe I am familiar enough with Puzzling SE to know that these ideas are not complex enough/based on logical thinking-enough to go here, and Gaming SE doesn't allow challenges. Nonetheless I believe this would make for a very enjoyable site.

Puzzling SE could be a kind of parent to Play SE, with those of us who enjoy it making sure it grows up right. It could be where the more casual challenge-makers, who might often get down-voted here for providing questions that are too simple, are directed to. What does the community think?

Comment: If you want to form a new SE, then [Area 51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) is what you want. Though other SE site metas can be used for promotion, of course.

Comment: @bobble Yes I was planning on posting this idea there originally, but came to the conclusion from their tag options that their discussion area was for discussion of proposals that have at least been defined. And when filling in the proposal submission form, we need to provide a link to a community that is ready to start promoting it. So I came to the conclusion that we need to actually have a community to start it first, and that's what I am asking here.

Comment: Ah darn, I didn't mean to link the meta site. Anyways, I'm not sure how well this would fit the SE system, but then Puzzling doesn't fit the SE system well anyways. I'll refrain from voting for now.

Comment: This sounds like it would very much not fit the format of Stack Exchange. Code Golf and PSE are special cases (and even here, we still have regular Q&A about puzzle design). You'd have a *very* hard time convincing people that this idea had enough value to make a new site.

Comment: And to be honest, I'm not sure I personally see value in it either. The purpose just appears to be "anything that's not a puzzle", which makes it very unfocused. It sounds like it would very easily get clogged up with low-effort questions that don't have any lasting value. I don't think the SE network would be a good fit for this idea at all - [/r/picturegame](http://old.reddit.com/r/picturegame) seems similar to what you're describing, though?

Comment: Okay it seems it won't work and that's perfectly fine. Should I delete the question or does someone want to write what you have said here as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The community here doesn't seem to think this is a good idea (see the comments on my question).

I eventually found a home for one of the ideas I mentioned on the [gaming meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15767/where-am-i-this-week-1).